# Whats the best approach when checking 500 errors on image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsonp, getjson

Would like to display additional images if a webservice I'm using goes down. Can someone display a general conditional statement.

Would like to parse jsonp, whoever within the js file the function changes name:

OX7289210029({my:example})

can I use a regexp to parse any JSONP function beginning with 'OX' Constant?

Comment: alert("general conditional statement");

Comment: This isn't like a food bank, you have to show some initiative, that you have tried and researched. Provide your own attempt (code).

Comment: @Knownasilya it's my first day using the site :-( ur super mean...

Comment: Sorry, didn't plan on being mean :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code to find out image exists or not:

```
function urlExists(testUrl) {
 var http = jQuery.ajax({
    type:"HEAD",
    url: testUrl,
    async: false
  })
  return http.status!=404;
}
```

than use

```
if(urlExists('urlToImgOrAnything') {
...
}
else {
...
}
```

Please check and let me know in case of any issue or concern.

Thanks and Regards,
Durgaprasad

Comment: Durgaprasad thanks your awesome bro it worked for me...However I want to parse jsonp with jquery. plugin creates a js file however the function wrapping the jsonp has an 'OX' constant but other numbers change (ie. OX9872384 next refresh OX2212347). Can I parse jsonp by calling any function using a regexp that has a constant beginning with 'OX'?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use plain javascript:

**Javascript**

```
var img = new Image(); //Create new Image object

img.src = "notexisting"; //notexisting = your own path

img.onerror = function() { alert("TEST"); } //Alerts test on failure
```

Or if you insist using jQuery...

**jQuery**

```
$("imageselector").error(function() {
    alert("Image error!");
});
```

Comment: This code is simple and very clean I actually thought of using this one as a fail safe if my code to attain jsonp and test for img doesn't work. However, thank you for your help